# How do I remove a node element by id in XML?

Tags: java, xml

Using: `javax.xml` and `org.w3c`:

```
public void removeNodeFromXML(File xmlfile_, String uuid)
  {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(xmlfile_);

    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer tFormer = tFactory.newTransformer();

   //????

   Element rootElement = doc.getRootElement();
   rootElement.removeChild("1236");

   //???

   // Normalize the DOM tree to combine all adjacent nodes
   doc.normalize();
   Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
   Result dest = new StreamResult(xmlfile_);
   tFormer.transform(source, dest);

  }
```

XML looks like this

```
<Servers>
 //remove this guy
 <server ID="1236">
  <name>Josh</name>
  <port>1234</port>
  <ip>12.2.2.3</ip>
 </server>

<server ID="1237">
  <name>John</name>
  <port>1234</port>
  <ip>12.2.2.3</ip>
 </server>
</Servers>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XPath to select specific elements/attributes. Just search the web for Tutorials. [Here is good one.](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/xPath/java-xpath.shtml) You should also read the [Java-Doc for java.xml.xpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html), which includes short examples.

The XPath-Expression for your XML-File is: `/server[@ID='xxxx']`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Element element = doc.getElementById("1236");
element.getParentNode().removeChild(element);
```

This should give you the element with ID "1236". You then get the parent node for the element and remove the element by passing the element with ID "1236" to removeChild.

See [here for a full example.](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/org.w3c.dom/RemNode.html)

Hope this helps.